# Visual Studio 2012 intellisense and C++: Resolve template typenames to real class name

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, typename

I have the following code:

```
class BundyRead
{
};

class BundyWrite
{
};

template<class T>
class BarBaseT
{
public:
    typedef T BundyType;

    BarBaseT()
        : bundy_(BundyType())
    {
    }

    BundyType& getBundy()
    {
        return bundy_;
    }

private:
    BundyType bundy_;
};

class BarRead : public BarBaseT<BundyRead>
{
};

class BarWrite : public BarBaseT<BundyWrite>
{
};

template<class T>
class FooBaseT
{
public:
    FooBaseT()
        : bar_(T())
    {
    }

    T& getBar()
    {
        return bar_;
    }

    typename T::BundyType& getBundy()
    {
        return getBar().getBundy();
    }

protected:
    T bar_;
};

class FooRead : public FooBaseT<BarRead>
{
};

class FooWrite : public FooBaseT<BarWrite>
{
};
```

Instantiating concrete *FooWrite* and call both methods:

```
FooWrite fooWrite;
fooWrite.getBar();
fooWrite.getBundy();
```

If I want to see the return type of `getBar()` with intellisense I see it resolved the template typename to `BarWrite`, which is great.
If I want to see the return type of `getBundy()` with intellisense it does not get resolved to `BundyWrite` as expected but

```
BarBaseT<BundyWrite>::BundyType&
```

I als noticed that if I use a typedef for `T` in `FooBaseT` and use that as the return type of `getBar()` instead of `T` it also does not get resolved to `BarWrite`. So I guess it has to do with the typedefs.

```
template<class T>
class FooBaseT
{
public:
    typedef typename T BarType;
...
BarType& getBar() {...}
...
};
```

I cant use something like `typename T::T` or something similar, right? Is there any chance to get the resolved concrete class types for intellisense? Otherwise its pretty hard to identify the correct return type for the user who uses my code.